# Could "force" magic render metal based bladed weapons obsolete?

Tags: magic

In my fantasy world magic allows for low-level blunt-force, object density manipulation (Impact/collision manipulation, damage amplification). These magic spells require physical touch, and they can't be used on living things so no enhancing the human body for example. These two spells combined would allow the user to increase and amplify the damage taken by the target, or to put it another way it would allow the user to manipulate the force/overall intensity of impact making an object easier to break/destroy or a person easier to defeat (smash into a bloody pulp). From an outside observer it would appear as if the weapon user is endowed with super-strength, it would basically allow someone to simulate super-strength. The way I am picturing it, it would allow for soldiers to ditch metal based swords and other bladed weaponsfor cheaper magically enhanced blunt weapons made out of even the most rudimentary of wood for example. With the added excuse of metal being harder to manipulate through magic due to some intrinsic property, this would render metal weapons overly expensive, redundant, maybe even useless. People would eventually turn to wood to make weapons, due to being readily available and cheaper. I assume combat style would be less slicing and more smashing, allowing for a more blunt trauma type of warfare (Also suppose shields would become useless, as people would rather dodge than risk getting smashed to pieces, speed thus becoming an important variable).

Comment: How expensive is it to magically enhance weapons, and how long do enhancements last?  Can nearly anyone enchant objects, or only rare specialists?

Comment: You bring up some interesting questions, didn't really think this through too much. But now that I think about it, not everybody can enchant objects, it would be limited to mages only (rare since magic is sanctionned by the states). Mages would enchant objects and deliver them to military personnel. Enhancts would not last forever that's for sure, ideally they would last as long as the average battle, but I'm still on the fence. It would be expensive for the average joe but not for law enforcement and soldiers (those who have a licence to used force on behalf of the state..something like that)

Comment: A possible further complication is that of equal and opposite reaction. In other words, unless it increases their durability as well, your enchanted baseball bats are going to shatter after one devastating hit.

Comment: Also if 2 weapons that are both enchanted are swung at each other, aside from the durability, how do you survive the inevitable shock waves?

Comment: @CaptainSkyfish I figured since I'm dealing with magic might as well go the easy route and just have the spell compensate and increase durability automatically, but only up to a certain point/threshold, so as not to make the weapon indestructible/ overpowered...

Comment: Yeah, that works too. But then, what about the good old fashioned quiet stabbing of your mother in law the queen at dinner time?

Comment: @Culyx Another good question that I didn't think about. I don't really know how I could tackle the issue but two ideas come to mind. One way to deal with this is to have spell be variable output one, thus whoever has higher output at the moment of collision wins, destroying the one with weaker output in the process. Another possibility is to have both break and cause physical damage to both users in the process (which only raises even more questions...).

Comment: @CaptainSkyfish  Stabbing is still very much common, metal knives and daggers remain useful for stealth assassinations/murder. On the battlefield however, these bladed tools (metal based) are but mere side weapons, being to brittle for 'savage' combat. (magically enchanted wooden polearm >>>>>>>>> sharp metal weapons).

Comment: As a vicious and aggressive local warlord, this means my agents will be quietly bribing, kidnapping, or killing all of my enemies' mages. Meanwhile, I'm going to need a larger castle to house and protect my own (and newly captured) mages from similar fates.

Comment: Can we have enchanted arrows and enchanted shield?

Comment: Honestly why not ? Then again it goes against what I was initally aiming for, basically blunt trauma only battles (bloody battles with people getting 1 hit KO-ed into bloody pulp, I was planning to counteract this by introducing magic negation later on). Also these spells require touch to work so shields are okay but would be quite risky I suppose, since the spell only increases durability of the shield and not the persons body so impact might just shatter your arm leaving the shield intact or something. Arrows don't work because as soon as they leave one's hand the spell loses its effect.

Comment: @Anonymousworldbuilding fun fact one of the safety things I've had to teach is don't hit hammers together, they're hardened steel, and if they shatter, they can send out dangerous (to your eyes) shrapnel, most people never see a hammer break; because most of the time your hitting stuff softer then a hammer (like nails, and your hand)

Answer (score 6):

**No**

Well, at least not how you described the magic system. If the magic can only be used while touching the object, then there's a metal-based bladed weapon I can think of that's incredibly useful on the battlefield which isn't in contact with the wielder when touching the enemy. That is to say, arrows. Arrows, and artillery in general, is a fantastic force multiplier when used correctly, and thus metal-based weapons won't be completely ignored.

I would agree with your assumption that metal personal weapons - i.e. swords, maces, lances, etc., the kind that you are holding onto when you use them on others - would definitely be replaced with wooden weapons. However, not necessarily battlehammers and clubs. Actually, I'd think the weapons would be replaced with gigantic longswords straight out of fantasy novels. If they weigh less and are stronger, you get bigger weapons. And while blunt trauma is tempting, remember that impact is just force / area, and thus not only will your blunt trauma be better, but your cutting edge on swords will be improved as well. Not to mention that swords can cut poles, so given that the combat will shift to giant weapons, everyone will be using sword-like weapons, because using a blunt hammer is asking to have a sword-user cut it in half. And then you're dead.

And that is also why shields are going to be gone. I'd imagine that magic-boosted shields will provide a defense against the magic-boosted weapons, but when you can wield a sword the size of a door, who needs a shield? Not to mention that you can take a set of wood armor and apply magic to that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaws in my reasoning ! However this really puts a wrench in my plans though, since I really wanted for swords and other bladed objects to be relegated to side weapons only (I don't mind artilery/long range though, just up close and personal combat). I really wanted for a more gruesome/impactful type of battle.

Comment: i can believe if you mean axe, but normal sword even 2h sword is unlikely to cut wooden pole unless the pole very thin or using soft wood, which as far as i know most of wooden blunt weapon use hard wood including quarterstaff, or it cut it multiple times in the same place over and over to be able to achieve that, but if you mean with the enhancement then probably......

Comment: @Anonymousworldbuilding i was gona show you this video though [wooden knife](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKH63_r0OCA) since halfthwed already make an answer and i think this related i put it here instead.

Comment: @Anonymousworldbuilding If you want *that*, then the way to do it is defensive spells. Specifically, a spell which nullifies impact damage by spreading it equally across the body. A sword, which concentrates damage, is mostly worthless. On the other hand, a massive hammer with a lot of weight deals a lot more kinetic energy is more effective. And you just whack people until their ability to spread the damage is overwhelmed and they explode into a pool of blood.

Comment: fighting with a sword and shield can be a lot more effective than a really big sword, the shield allows you to close, and a shorter sword will be more maneuverable regardless of weightlessness.

Comment: @Anonymousworldbuilding if you want blade weapon to be obsolete then i think you need armor or protection that can defense against cut,slash,hack, and trust. or if you dont mind trust then make something like plate armor the only way to break it is using blunt weapon and stabbing weapon like lance or dagger even sword end up use halfswording or using murder strike to bash or stab through the plate gap but sometimes axe can break it though since it also deliver some blunt or hook the person.....

Comment: @LiJun lot's of good ideas here, I think I'm going to mix up elements of Halfthawed and your own answers.

Comment: @Halfthawed I'm going to add light stab-proof armor ( so no plate armor, since I'm looking for something light enough so that it won't slow down fighters since speed is very much a important variable) and nifty impact damage nullifying/dampening/spreading spells to boot. That way I get to have my cake and eat it to, blunt weapon as main form of weaponry (hurray for the gore), bladed weapons (just in case, or for elaborate stabbing moves) on the side and finally no shields. Thanks again !

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**

Congratulations. Guns are super easy in your world. You no longer need gunpowder to launch projectiles. Just have the hammer hit a metal ball with its mega increased force. The hammer on the gun is constantly in contact with the mage and the ball takes all the force and becomes a destructive force all its own.

For that matter, ballista, catapults, etc. gain a lot of extra power as well. Just apply a force enchant to the launching mechanism and get rid of bulky counterweights.

Comment: Interesting, I guess this will come in handy later on in this world's timeline. Also thanks for pointing out the fact that this would also make the most rudimentary of artillery weapon 'super overpowered', that's definitely going to be a huge problem/headache (a good thing though).